# Wow.js not taking two classes for an element at different time intervals

Tags: javascript, wow.js

I have an **image** element, on which I want to apply *two animation classes*, one on the arrival and one on some fixed time.

For Example, on arrival i want a ***fadeIn*** effect. So i do this:

```
img.classList.add("wow");
img.classList.add("fadeIn");
```

I again want to add a **heartbeat** effect on the same image after some time. So i tried something like this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    img.classList.remove("fadeIn");
    img.classList.add("heartBeat");
},3000);
```

This is not working, and the hearbeat effect is not seen.

**Note:**

On the other hand, if I don't initially set up the **fadeIn** effect to the image, then the image does take the **heartbeat** effect after 3000ms.

So a standalone code like this one, is working perfectly fine.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    img.classList.add("heartBeat");
},3000);
```

I am not being able to figure out the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can cuse the function inside the `callback` of the WOW instance.

According to the [wow.js docs](https://github.com/graingert/wow), it is fired every time an animation is started and the "the argument that is passed in is the DOM node being animated" (`box`, but in this case I'm directly using the `img` variable).

So, when it is triggered, we can immediately remove the `.fadeIn` class, which will not affect the animation because it was added inline with JavaScript. In addition, after 3 seconds, we remove the style attribute (that caused the "fade in" animation) and add the `.heartBeat` class that will trigger the next heartbeat animation.

```
img.classList.add("wow");
img.classList.add("fadeIn");

new WOW({
  callback: function(box) {
    img.classList.remove("fadeIn");
    setTimeout(function () {
      img.removeAttribute("style");
      img.classList.add("heartBeat");
    },3000);
  }
}).init();
```